# How To Track Down Silverlight Style and Template Issues

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a very large silverlight application. I am using a telerik RadGridView control.

I noticed that the header style of the RadGridView is not the standard header as given out of the box by telerik. I.e. the colours are different and the text is different etc.

I first tried to define my own styles and templates (which work in a test project). They are ignored by the RadGridView.

So I started hunting around our application to find out whether a template or style has been applied to make the header different. I couldn't find it.

Are there tools out there that can show me what templates / styles are applied to a particular control and where they come from? A way to debug it in effect.

I am using silverlight spy, but the free edition doesn't show me everything I need.

UPDATE:

I can see what is happening here, a theme is being applied like this,

Telerik.Windows.Controls.StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new  Telerik.Windows.Controls.Windows7Theme();

So the theme must be overiding any template and styles changes that I apply.

Comment: *but the free edition doesn't show me everything I need* - what do you think you are missing from it that would be helpful?

Comment: When you load a RadGridView into EB there are multiple drill downs to see all the many styles and templates.  I don't know about the free edition... But it would take all the embedded resources and the .xaml from your main page to be able to help.

Comment: Where do you set the theme to `Windows7Theme`? App.xaml code behind?